# How do you attack with your backup weapon?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I am playing on PC.

For example, my sniper has a pistol. How do I have him shoot using the pistol rather than his sniper rifle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can press X on the keyboard, or just click on the weapon in the bottom right with your mouse. With a gamepad you hit X to swap weapons (as far as I can tell this doesn't count as an action).

Comment: I think it's X on the keyboard, too. But you can just mouse click on the weapon down in the bottom right. There's currently even a bug where you can put a sniper in overwatch with a pistol, then switch to sniper rifle, and he'll use that for overwatch, if you're feeling all cheatery!

Comment: I specifically asked for an answer for PC.

Comment: FWIW, I use the gamepad on PC, and I'm sure others do as well, hence my original answer.

Comment: Mostly important for reaction shots (overwatch, etc): the currently equipped weapon will be used.  So be aware of that when ending your turn.

Comment: Beware -- clicking the weapon with your mouse can be fatal. If was already selected and partially empty it will reload and that trooper has lost the rest of his turn. The X key is safer.

Comment: Note that Heavies cannot directly swap to their secondary, which is their rocket launcher - you use the rocket launcher with your skills, and only a limited number of times per mission.